# Contact Form Sending 3 Copies to Recipient

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a contact form on my website which calls a .php mail handler to send off the inquiries.  Each time an inquiry is sent off I receive 3 copies of the email.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

The following script is in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('#form').TMForm({ 
ownerEmail:'admin@endlessflooring.co.nz'
})
})
</script>
```

The contact form is as follows:

```
<form id="form">                              
<div class="success_wrapper">
<div class="success-message">Contact form submitted</div>
</div>
<label class="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" data-constraints="@Required 

@JustLetters" />
<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
<span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
</label>

<label class="email">

<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
<span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
</label>

<label class="phone">

<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers"/>
<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
<span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
</label>

<label class="state">
 <input type="text" placeholder="City" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"/>
<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
<span class="error-message">*This is not a valid city.</span>
</label>        

<label class="message">

<textarea placeholder="Message" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=2,max=999999)'></textarea>
<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
<span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
</label>
<div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="btns">

<a href="#" data-type="submit" class="link1">send message</a></div>
</div>
</form>
```

And the mail handler is as follows:

```
<?php

    //SMTP server settings  
    $host = "smtp.host.com";
    $port = "587";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";


    $messageBody = "";

    if($_POST['name']!='false'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Name: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['email']!='false'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }else{
        $headers = '';
    }

    if($_POST['phone']!='false'){       
        $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }   
    if($_POST['state']!='false'){       
        $messageBody .= '<p>Suburb: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['message']!='false'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
        $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
    }

    if($host=="" or $username=="" or $password==""){
        $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
        $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $subject = 'Endless Flooring Quote Request';

        try{ 
            if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
                throw new Exception('mail failed');
                }else{
                echo 'mail sent';
            }
            }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
        }
    }else{  
        require_once 'Mail.php';

        $to = $_POST["owner_email"];
        $subject = 'Endless Flooring Quote Request' . $_POST["name"];
        $headers = array (
        'From' => 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n",
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject);

        $smtp = Mail::factory(
                    'smtp',
                    array (
                        'host' => $host,
                        'port' => $port,
                        'auth' => true,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $messageBody);

        try{
            if(PEAR::isError($mail)){
                echo $mail->getMessage();
                }else{
                echo 'mail sent';
            }
            }catch(Exception $mail){
            echo $mail->getMessage() ."\n";
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Are you using different emails for recipient, owner and sender? Do you know where the form submission code is? That is what happens when you hit submit on the page?

Comment: Sorry not sure about the different email address?  I only request one email from the person filling in the form.  The form code on the page is just before the footer.  When you hit submit it brings up a box at the top of the form saying your message has been submitted or something similar.

Comment: It's hard to know without the rest of hte code but `$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $messageBody);`  had the owner email in both `$to` and in `$headers`